# warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers

This typedef works:

```
typedef void (*mem_deallocator)(void*);
```

However this one

```
typedef void* (*mem_allocator)(size_t);
```

gives the warning:

> warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]

I'm using GCC 4.8.1 and I'm compiling with `-c -Wall`.

How to fix the code so I won't get the warning any more?

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` or stddef.h I guess.

Comment: @Mat stddef.h it was! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size_t` is defined in the following headers, you need to include at least one of them.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wchar.h>   //since C99
#include <uchar.h>   //since C11
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. If a parameter definition has only "one word", it should figure out it's the type, not the name, and error out accordingly.

Comment: I searched over the standard to make sure that's the whole list of headers, hopefully so.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, stddef.h is the strictest I think. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Flavius: g++ will give you the true error: "‘size_t’ was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @Flavius: In the absence of a visible declaration, `size_t` is just an ordinary identifier -- and an ordinary identifier cannot be a type name. Typedefs have to be treated specially, in effect becoming context-sensitive keywords. Parsing C is hard.